# Create a Google Calendar event two weeks into the future, using information from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'd like use a script to add an event, named after the the active workbook tab, to my calendar. The event should start two weeks in the future. How would I do that?

My current code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent('Check on status of re:'+name+' application',
     new Date('July 20, 1969')); //this should be two weeks from now
  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

  var date = new Date();
    var d = new Date(date.getTime()+14*3600000*24);



  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent('Check re:'+name+' application',
     d); //this should be two weeks from now

}
```

Comment: This will have issues when there are time zone differences. Consider a more robust approach than simply adding 14 days worth of milliseconds.

Comment: nah this is fine